# Using Hough transform to compute similarity

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

Can I use Hough matrix to compute similarity of two binary images in MATLAB?  
`[H,T,R] = hough(bw)` H is Hough matrix and bw is binary image.

Answer (score 4):

You may find this paper of use: "Similarity Evaluation in Image Retrieval Using the Hough Transform" - http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.25.7781

Comment: How can I make it orientation invariant?

Comment: @Sam: Unfortunately, I don't know.